func.count doubles the result value in flask-sqlachemy query
A query across 4 tables results in an doubled value for an func.count on an column of the tables.
I query 4 tables to generate competition certificates for the podium.
teams = Groups.query.with_entities(Groups.name, func.coalesce(func.sum(Distances.distance), 0).label("distance"), func.count(GroupsToParticipants.group_id).label("counter")).filter_by(grouptype_id=grouptype.id).join(GroupsToParticipants, Groups.id==GroupsToParticipants.group_id, isouter=True).join(GroupTypes, Groups.grouptype_id==GroupTypes.id, isouter=True).join(Distances, GroupsToParticipants.participant_id==Distances.participant_id, isouter=True).group_by(Groups.id).order_by(desc(func.sum(Distances.distance))).limit(3).all()

Tables
class GroupTypes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tblGroupTypes"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="PK_GroupTypes"),
    )
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Group Type: {self.name}>"

class Groups(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tblGroups"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    grouptype_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="PK_Groups"),
        UniqueConstraint("name", name="UQ_Groups_Name"),
        Index("IX_Groups_GroupTypeID", "grouptype_id"),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(["grouptype_id"], ["tblGroupTypes.id"], name="FK_Groups_GroupTypes", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="NO ACTION"),
    )
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Group Name: {self.name}>"

class GroupsToParticipants(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tblGroupsToParticipants"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, autoincrement=True)
    participant_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    group_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="PK_GroupToParticipants"),
        Index("IX_GroupsToParticipants_ParticipantID", "participant_id"),
        Index("IX_GroupsToParticipants_GroupID", "group_id"),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(["participant_id"], ["tblParticipants.id"], name="FK_GroupsToParticipants_Participants", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(["group_id"], ["tblGroups.id"], name="FK_GroupsToParticipants_Groups", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
    )
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Participant ID - Group ID: {self.participant_id} {self.group_id}>"

class Distances(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tblDistances"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, autoincrement=True)
    participant_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    barcode: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(9), nullable=True)
    distance: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=True)
    night: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(9), nullable=True)
    timestamp: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name="PK_Distances"),
        Index("IX_Distances_ParticipantID", "participant_id"),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(["participant_id"], ["tblParticipants.id"], name="FK_Distances_Participants", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
    )
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Distance Barcode: {self.barcode}>"

Table GroupTypes



id
name




1
families


2
teams


3
companies


4
clubs



Table Groups



id
name
grouptype_id




39
test team
2


40
test family
1


41
test team 2
2



Table Distances



id
participant_id
barcode
distance
night
timestamp




170
560
1170X1560
1000
none
2024-04-14 09:36:01


171
560
1171X1560
NULL
none
NULL


172
563
1172X1563
1500
none
2024-04-14 12:07:15


173
563
1173X1563
NULL
none
NULL


174
564
1174X1564
500
none
2024-04-14 09:38:20



Table GroupsToParticipants



id
participant_id
group_id




76
556
39


77
563
40


78
564
40


79
572
41



The query should return



name
distance
counter




test team
0
1


test family
2000
2


test team 2
0
1



but returns



name
distance
counter




test team
0
2


test family
2000
4


test team 2
0
2



How can i fix this issue?

What is the SQL that is generated if you use print(Groups.query.with_entities(Groups.name, func.coalesce(func.sum(Distances.distance), 0).label("distance"), func.count(GroupsToParticipants.group_id).label("counter")).filter_by(grouptype_id=grouptype.id).join(GroupsToParticipants, Groups.id==GroupsToParticipants.group_id, isouter=True).join(GroupTypes, Groups.grouptype_id==GroupTypes.id, isouter=True).join(Distances, GroupsToParticipants.participant_id==Distances.participant_id, isouter=True).group_by(Groups.id).order_by(desc(func.sum(Distances.distance))).limit(3))?

The SQL is SELECT "tblGroups".name, coalesce(sum("tblDistances".distance), :coalesce_1) AS distance, count("tblGroupsToParticipants".group_id) AS counter  FROM "tblGroups" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tblGroupsToParticipants" ON "tblGroups".id = "tblGroupsToParticipants".group_id LEFT OUTER JOIN "tblGroupTypes" ON "tblGroups".grouptype_id = "tblGroupTypes".id LEFT OUTER JOIN "tblDistances" ON "tblGroupsToParticipants".participant_id = "tblDistances".participant_id  WHERE "tblGroups".grouptype_id = :grouptype_id_1 GROUP BY "tblGroups".id ORDER BY sum("tblDistances".distance) DESC  LIMIT :param_1

Great, now I would write the plain SQL that gives you your desired result and compare that with what SQLAlchemy has generated. Using COALESCE here doesn't feel correct, I think you'd be better off putting together a few sub-queries. Once you've got a SQL query to aim for you can retro-engineer the SQLAlchemy query.

I solved it using a subquery: group_count = Groups.query.with_entities(Groups.id, func.count(GroupsToParticipants.participant_id).label("counter")).filter_by(grouptype_id=grouptype.id).join(GroupsToParticipants, Groups.id==GroupsToParticipants.group_id, isouter=True).group_by(GroupsToParticipants.group_id).subquery()

teams = Groups.query.with_entities(Groups.name, func.coalesce(func.sum(Distances.distance), 0).label("distance"), group_count.c.counter.label("count")).filter_by(grouptype_id=grouptype.id).join(GroupsToParticipants, Groups.id==GroupsToParticipants.group_id, isouter=True).join(GroupTypes, Groups.grouptype_id==GroupTypes.id, isouter=True).join(Distances, GroupsToParticipants.participant_id==Distances.participant_id, isouter=True).join(group_count, Groups.id==group_count.c.id, isouter=True).group_by(Groups.id).order_by(desc(func.sum(Distances.distance))).limit(3).all()
